# How to compile a table of data in google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a total script kitty at best and am trying to use google apps scripts to automate a process for me.  Here a sample table like the one I am working with(data is in google sheets spreadsheet):

| Variety | Category | Peter | Courtney |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DP | HBC | 0.00 | 4.5 |
| DP | MNG | 2.00 | 0 |
| UB | THN | 7.00 | 0 |
| 471H | THN | 5.00 | 0 |
| 471H | THN | 0.00 | 5 |
| GRH | FST | 4.00 | 0 |
| GRH | THN | 8.00 | 0 |
| GRH | THN | 0.00 | 8 |
| GRH | THN | 0.00 | 8 |
| HM | HBC | 6.50 | 0 |
| HM | HBC | 0.00 | 6.5 |
| HM | MNG | 2.00 | 0 |
| HM | MNG | 0.00 | 2 |
| CL | HBC | 8.50 | 0 |
| CL | HBC | 7.00 | 0 |
| PSV | HBC | 2.50 | 0 |
| PSV | HBC | 7.00 | 0 |
| PSV | HBC | 0.00 | 2.5 |

The table shows the employees reported hours broken down by Variety and category.  My goal is to compile this data so if the employees work at the same category and same variety I want all hours expressed in a single line.  For instance if you look at the last two rows of the data you'll notice that the Variety and Category columns are matching which means the data should be compiled. So instead of:

| Variety | Category | Peter | Courtney |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PSV | HBC | 7.00 | 0 |
| PSV | HBC | 0.00 | 2.5 |

I want to compile the data like this:

| Variety | Category | Peter | Courtney |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PSV | HBC | 7.00 | 2.5 |

I am trying to do this from the bottom up because I heard going from the top down can cause issues but I am open to any suggestions.  I think I need to write a for loop that compares the variety box of the active row to the variety box of the above row AND compares if the category box of the active row is equal to the category box of the above row and if both are true add the hours of both the "Peter" column and "Courtney" column.

I know there is more to do on top of that but this for loop is what I really need help on, unless you can suggest a better way?

Thanks for looking at my work,
JP

Stackoverflow member Ruben has asked me to elaborate more, here is where I am at:

I found a stackoverflow answer that pushed me in the direction of how to parse the data with the for loop.  Here is the for loop skeleton I am working with:

```
function project() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("gest");
    var data = sheet.getRange('A2:F19').getValues();
// Category and Variety columns
    var leadV = sheet.getRange('B18');
    var followV = sheet.getRange('B19');
    var leadC = sheet.getRange('C18');
    var followC = sheet.getRange('C19');
// Hour columns
    var leadH1 = sheet.getRange('E18');
    var followH1 = sheet.getRange('E19');
    var leadH2 = sheet.getRange('F18');
    var followH2 = sheet.getRange('F19');

    
    
    for (var i = 0 ;i < data.length ; i++)
    if leadV === followV AND leadC === followC, 
    // add both hours columns together
        leadH1.getValue()+followH1.getValue()
        leadH2.getValue()+followH2.getValue();
        //Delete active row(not made yet)
        else continue;
    sheet.getRange(18-i, 2).activate();
```

My idea was to have a "lead" row and a "follow" row that would compare themselves and work up the data one by one through the for loop.  I realize I need to use getActiveCell(), rather then getRange() but I don't understand how to compare an adjacent cell to the active cell while wrapping it into the for loop.  I am just a bit overwhelmed and I think I might be over complicating my situation.

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Do not add your findings in a comment, instead [edit] the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to using a formula instead of script, I can propose a solution. (In my own practice of decades, I save script for *only* those times when formulas cannot produce the desired result; this cuts down greatly on potential problems.)

This solution uses information from the script in your post to ascertain that the name of the source sheet is 'gest' and the ranges of data to include in the new report are B:C and E:F.

Create a new sheet and place the following formula in cell A1:

`=ArrayFormula({gest!B1:C1, gest!E1:F1; QUERY({gest!B2:C, E2:F},"Select Col1, Col2, SUM(Col3), SUM(Col4) WHERE Col1 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1, Col2 LABEL SUM(Col3) '', SUM(Col4) ''")})`

This single formula will produce all headers and results, and will "keep up" as you add new rows of data in the 'gest' sheet.

A virtual array is formed between the curly brackets { }. This is a way of "sticking together" non-contiguous data in new ways.

The headers are grabbed by the two references preceding the semicolon.

Then a `QUERY` is formed from the non-header information in the target columns.

In plain English, the `Select` clause of the `QUERY` reads "Return four columns: exactly what is in the first requested column and the second requested column followed by the categorized sums from the third and fourth requested columns, separating (i.e., "`GROUP`ing") those sums by each unique pairing from the first two columns." The `LABEL` section just removes technical headers from the sum columns created (which would otherwise have placed stock headers of 'sum' above each of the summed columns).

Comment: Dude thank you so much for this, this really helps me a lot and helps me better understand the QUERY function in sheets/excel.  I very much appreciate your time and expertise.

Comment: My pleasure. And just to be extra clear, to my knowledge, Excel does not currently offer use of QUERY; only Google Sheets does. Excel does allow SQL Queries of a sort using a wizard; but the process and language is very different.